# Determine all values of scalars p, q and r for which given linear systems is consistent.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

So I am trying to figure out if I am doing this problem correctly, I need to do the following  **Determine all values of scalars p;q and r for which given linear systems is consistent**

$$\begin{Bmatrix}
4 & 6 & p \\
-2 & -1 & q \\
\end{Bmatrix}$$

so far I have it converted as follows ~
$$\begin{Bmatrix}
1 & 6/4 & p1/4 \\
-2 & -1 & q \\
\end{Bmatrix}$$

then ~
$$\begin{Bmatrix}
1 & 6/4 & p1/4 \\
0 & 2 & qp1/2 \\
\end{Bmatrix}$$

then 
$$\begin{Bmatrix}
1 & 6/4 & p1/4 \\
0 & 1 & qp1/4 \\
\end{Bmatrix}$$

then
$$\begin{Bmatrix}
1 & 0 & -(p5/4) \\
0 & 1 & qp1/4 \\
\end{Bmatrix}$$

from here I feel like the way this table reduced down I did something wrong, but if it isn't then I believe these would then be consistent since it has a unique solution.

side note there is suppose to be no r involved in this question

Thank in advance.

Comment: Every time you've manipulated $p$ and $q$, you've seemingl made a basic mistake of algebra (except the first time, when you divided the first rwo by $4$).

Answer (score 1):

The matrix
$$ \begin{bmatrix} 4 & 6 \\ -2 & 1 \end{bmatrix} $$
has nonzero determinant, meaning the matrix is nonsingular and so, its column space is all of $\mathbb{R}^2$, so there is a linear combination of the columns (a solution to the linear system of equations) that gives rise to $\begin{bmatrix} p \\ q \end{bmatrix}$, regardless of the values of $p$ and $q$.

In order to see this through row reduction, the row reduction should actually look like so:
$$\left[\begin{array}{rr|r}
    4 & 6 & p \\
    -2 & 1 & q 
  \end{array}\right] \implies
\left[\begin{array}{rr|r}
    1 & 3/2 & p/4 \\
    -2 & 1 & q 
  \end{array}\right] \implies
\left[\begin{array}{rr|r}
    1 & 3/2 & p/4 \\
    0 & 4 & p/2 + q 
  \end{array}\right] \implies
\left[\begin{array}{rr|r}
    1 & 3/2 & p/4 \\
    0 & 1 & p/8 + q/4 
  \end{array}\right] \implies
\left[\begin{array}{rr|r}
    1 & 0 & p/16 - 3q/8  \\
    0 & 1 & p/8+q/4 
  \end{array}\right]
$$

Again, we see that, this agrees with what we said earlier: the matrix is nonsingular, and so invertible, so regardless of $p,q$, we can always solve:
\begin{align*}
\begin{bmatrix} 4 & 6 \\ -2 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix} &= \begin{bmatrix} p \\ q \end{bmatrix} \\
\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix} &= \begin{bmatrix} 4 & 6 \\ -2 & 1 \end{bmatrix}^{-1} \begin{bmatrix} p \\ q \end{bmatrix} \\
&= \frac{1}{16}\begin{bmatrix} 1 & -6 \\ 2 & 4 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} p \\ q \end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}

Comment: Ah, see we have not learned about invertible yet, but I believe I understand what you are saying. I also see my silly algebra mistake now I did above, but without using invertible was my assumption of since there was a constant variable of x1 and x2 that it makes p and q constants?

Comment: Yes. The fact that you can find a solution $(x_1, x_2)$ that solves the system of equations means the system is consistent.

Comment: Awesome, okay so then so then $$\begin{Bmatrix} 1 & 0 &p/16 - 3q/8 \\ 0 & 1 & p/8 + q/4\\ \end{Bmatrix}$$ is the proper form for the final answer of this question?